# How to find a nested connected component using enzyme mount?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React Login, connected component:

```
class Login extends React.Component<ComponentProps, ComponentState> {

  public constructor(props: ComponentProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }
  ...
}

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(withRouter(withStyles(styles)(Login)));
```

I would like to test that the state is populated properly as the user enters his credentials:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { mount, ReactWrapper } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { state } from 'tests/fixtures';
import Login, { ComponentState } from './Login';

const mockStore = configureStore();
const store = mockStore(state);

let wrapper: ReactWrapper<any, Readonly<{}>, React.Component<{}, {}, any>>;

beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><Router><Login /></Router></Provider>);
});

it('should populate the state with credentials', () => {
  const loginInstance = wrapper.find('* > * > * > * > * > * > * > Login').instance();

  const inputUsername = wrapper.find('.testUsername input');
  inputUsername.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'someusername' } });
  expect((loginInstance.state as ComponentState).username).toEqual('someusername');

  const inputPassword = wrapper.find('.testPassword input');
  inputPassword.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'mySecretPassword' } });
  expect((loginInstance.state as ComponentState).password).toEqual('mySecretPassword');
});
```

wrapper.debug() looks as follow:

```
<Provider store={{...}}>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Router history={{...}}>
      <ConnectFunction>
        <withRouter(WithStyles(Login)) dispatchLogin={[Function: dispatchLogin]}>
          <Route>
            <WithStyles(Login) dispatchLogin={[Function: dispatchLogin]} history={{...}} location={{...}} match={{...}} staticContext={[undefined]}>
              <Login...
```

The tests are passing, but I would like to improve my component finding method.
I tried wrapper.find(Login) as shown on the enzyme doc, but the Component is not found. The only way it can be found is doing it as shown above.
https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html

How can I find connected components with enzyme mount?

Comment: if you only want to test the `state` of the `Login` component, why don't you export the `Login` component (with named export) : `export class Login extends React` and test it outside of `react-redux`, `react-router` etc.. You just need to `import {Login} from './Login';` in your test

Comment: I did that for some other tests. In this case I'm manipulating text fields (Material UI components) and need to have them rendered. That wouldn't work with a shallow wrapper, any tip? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

'Login' was my connected component but it should be your component (not connected), as in:

```
export class Login extends React.Component<ComponentProps, ComponentState> {
  ...
}
```

So your tests will look like:

```
// Import the connected components (to mount) and the component
import ConnectedLogin, { Login } from './Login';

// Wrap the connected component
const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><Router><ConnectedLogin /></Router></Provider>);

// Find the component that is NOT connected
const loginInstance = wrapper.find(Login).instance();
```